# Cannot delete a row from mysql with php code

Tags: php, mysql

so i m trying to delete a row in mysql with php code and it doesnt gets deleted

the code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['zbrisi']))
    {
        $ime = $_POST['imeDatoteke'];
        mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        mysql_select_db("upload");
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM datoteke WHERE imeDatoteke=$ime");
        mysql_close();
        echo "<strong>Podatki so bili zbrisani!</strong>";
    }
?>



<input name="imeDatoteke" type="text" />

<input type="submit" name="zbrisi" value="Zbriši" />
```

and the database:
[image]

Comment: try as `imeDatoteke='$ime'`

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions or PDO instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)!!!

Comment: No to mention your code is wide open to SQL Injection which is more reason to move into MySQLi or PDO using prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value in the where - condition to be deleted is a string, it must be enclosed in `'`:

```
...
mysql_query("DELETE FROM datoteke WHERE imeDatoteke = '" . $ime. "' ");
...
```

Comment: yes that id work thanks alot i will rate as an answers as soon as i can

Comment: At least point out SQL injection and answer with a prepared statement or so instead of just encouraging people to use posted variables literally.

Comment: @Blizz: You know that this is the entire code ready for production, do you? And why not posting all the rest of programming rules related to database queries? I'm tired of these smartass recommendations not serving any purpose.

Comment: Save the sarcasm. People come here to ask questions and if there is a possible improvement or a security issue with it, it is the duty of the more experienced programmers to point that out. I'm so tired of people just sitting here for the reputation instead of doing what this site was built to do: Help others improve their code. If you view this single possible injection point (which is enough to hack the entire site) as not important enough to point out, perhaps you should consider not replying anymore. My $0.02.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM datoteke WHERE imeDatoteke='$ime'");
```

Comment: Use mysqli_* functions or PDO statements instead of using mysql_* functions(deprecated)!!!